# Using different public keys on the same (encrypted) column

Tags: postgresql, encryption

Generally, when encrypting sensitive-data columns, we use the same public key for all the rows. I have noticed that it is possible to use different public keys for different rows. For example, sensitive-data column for department A is encrypted with Key-A, and so on.

When this is done, a SELECT query that is conditional on the encrypted column and that spans rows where the encrypted column is encrypted with different public keys will return an error.

However, a SELECT query that covers only department A and uses the private key corresponding to Key-A will succeed - because all the encrypted column values can be decrypted with the provided private key.

Can I can use this to implement a form of row-level encryption / security? Is this already a standard technique - if so, what's it called, where can I read more?

Comment: Why DBA migrated the question here? Didn't pgcrypto extension work for you? You can decrease the scope of your question by asking there how to do it with pgcrypto.

Comment: [pgsodium One Key ID per Row with Nonce Support and Associated Data](https://github.com/michelp/pgsodium#one-key-id-per-row-with-nonce-support-and-associated-data) does this.

Comment: @defalt I am already doing it with `pgcrypto`. I wanted to know if this is a legit approach with a proper name. DBA migrated because I requested it. I requested it because I got no response/comment there.

Comment: Thanks for the *pgsodium* reference. Very helpful.